# The code will only work once

Tags: networkx

The code I am using with networkx seems to only work once per time I run it. I'm not sure why this is at all.

```
    import networkx as nx
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    edgelist=[1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,2,4,5,2,5,2,5,6,3]
    e=edgelist
    def global_clustering(list_of_edges):
        return global_cluster(list_of_edges)

    def makegraph(g):
        graph1 = nx.Graph()
        graph1.add_nodes_from(nodes(g))
        g1=g
        while len(g1)>0:
            graph1.add_edge(g1[0], g1[1])
            del g1[0:2]
        return graph1

    def global_cluster(list1):
        graph=makegraph(list1)
        print nx.transitivity(graph)
```

Really, I just want to find the transitivity of the graph, otherwise known as global clustering coefficient. It's a function which comes with networkx. 
Thanks for the help

Comment: all the code you've given does right now is create an list called `edgelist` and define some functions.  It doesn't do anything with those functions or the list.  What happens, and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Basically, if I want to run the function twice, it will come up with an error tue second time, and third, and 4th, etc.

Comment: I think Aric's probably right, but if his answer isn't right it's because  it's not clear what you're after.  If you run **what** function twice?  Please edit with the following in mind: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: My apologies. I meant the global cluster function. I forgot I had 2 functions. When I do global_cluster(edgelist) it will give me the answer. The second time I try to do this it comes up with an error

Comment: and what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this is what you want:

```
import networkx as nx
edgelist=[1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,2,4,5,2,5,2,5,6,3]
edges = zip(edgelist[::2],edgelist[1::2])
graph = nx.Graph(edges)
print(nx.transitivity(graph))
```